# Approach for IT Support assistance

Tags: hardware, asset-management, manage

Let's say that you are a company that gives IT Support. Your client contact you to have a price quotation to give IT Support for the following areas: Network (Wifi included) Servers Storage Cloud services

In order to have an idea, which steps would you follow to understand what's the impact of the work?

As first, I believe you need to know what's the number and the status of the assets you need to give assistance to. This implies an inventory of the hardware, software, license and warranty status, from 10000ft view.

Do you have any experience on how to conduct this analysis? Thanks.

.: Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, bringing on a new support customer should involve an assessment of what they have and some stuff about what the customer is, and does. Asset counts matter at certain scales, as does user count, and site count.

You should also detail what's in-scope and out-of-scope (or extra cost) for the support contract.

It sounds like you're trying to start a Managed Service Provider company? I feel like you should already have some ideas about these sorts of things. If your business plan is "I will ask strangers on the internet to help make my pricing and engagement strategy, for free", I'm worried you're not going to be successful.

And this question is probably out of scope for this site, and certainly way too large to answer generically.

Comment: No, that's not my aim. I would like to understand what is the correct approach to do this kind of analysis.
Along with this, any documentation you can share would be useful.
Please don't try to guess or judge other's intentions, just answer if you know the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking for something very detailed. "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask